# Is there a way to create a hyperlink that can be reused and updated from a single locaton?

Tags: url, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint site that will have several hyperlinks to send an email to certain people. I'd like this to have long-term stability For example, if I need to create a mailto hyperlink to the billing administrator and that email changes when a new person takes the role, I can update that email in one location and everywhere that link was used, the email is now changed.

I've seen this work on WP sites using plugins that support reusable text/content blocks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Content Editor Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc) usually this web part is used to add html and js content into the site

There are three ways you can add content to the Content Editor Web Part:

1. **Rich Text Editor**    You can use the Rich Text Editor to type
   formatted content automatically without prior knowledge of HTML
   syntax. Click the buttons on the Standard and Formatting toolbars at
   the top of the window to enter and format the content. Click Help on
   the Standard toolbar to display a summary of the tasks that you can
   perform and their corresponding buttons.
2. **Source Editor**    You can use the Source Editor to enter or modify
   HTML source code. The Source Editor is a plain text editor and is
   intended for users who are familiar with HTML syntax.
3. **Content Link**    Instead of editing content, you can link to existing
   content by entering a hyperlink to a text file that contains HTML
   source code. The two valid hyperlink protocols that you can use are:

   Hypertext Transfer Protocol (http://)

   Hypertext Transfer Protocol with privacy, which uses Secure Sockets
   Layer (SSL) encryption (https://)

   You can use an absolute URL or a relative URL. However, you cannot
   use a file path.

in your case you should use **Content Link** as content source after adding this file in document library in your site so in this case this html file will be centralize in one place and referenced in all places in your site once you want to change it you will change it in one place inside this document library.

file content e.g.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20world" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. So for example, within this text file, if I want it to include a mailto I would have the following? `<a href="mailto:name@email.com">Link text</a>`

Comment: welcome, yes it is a normal html file you can include any html tag inside it.

Comment: So I'm trying to have this listed within a post, but it's not working. Here is an example. When I click, nothing happens. `<body>
<a href="mailto:someome@email.com">Link text</a>
</body>`

Comment: you don't need to add body element inside html file because it will be injected to the page if the link is not working check default mail application on your OS and set it to any client mail e.g. outlook and try again